# Problems with outputs in neural networks (in MATLAB's neural networks toolbox)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I trained my [artificial neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) (ANN) in MATLAB with 652,500 data points, and in another blind test (652,100 data points - for completely new input data sets) the output is excellent (as I want). But the problem occurs when I insert very less amount of data (for example, below 50 data points). The output is quite unexpected, and I checked it many times.

To be more precise, the training phase contains 10% data for training, 45% for validation and 45% for testing. The training is quite successful, and for large amount of new input data it works very well. The problem is when very limited data (compared to training data points) are inserted in the neural network, it shows quite unrealistic output, beyond the range on what it was trained.

Why is this so? Could anyone light some sheds on this please?

Also mention please, is there any strict (hard and fast) rules on training and final testing data points? For example: what percent of training data should be / must be introduced in the new input data sets. I guess the problem is my network overestimate or underestimate the output as very less percentage of data it receives as compared to training phase.

Comment: Try shuffling the data before you split in train/validation/test and see whether that behaviour is recurrent or not. It could be that the data space is not properly covered over the data used for the test in the 'limited data' case and that when you have more data for testing, those errors are 'masked' in the average by the others.

Comment: I understood your logic, many thanks. 
My datasets are already shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is over-fitting of the dataset in duration of training. Data dividing is a very important task in training of a neural network. In general and more scientifically, the percentage of the training set should be between 70-80%. Test and validation sets should be each on around 10-15%. For instance:

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
```

You imagine a student in a class. `TrainRatio` is materials/lectures that should be learned by student. `ValRatio` is the percentage of the materials that should be examined as a middle-term examination, and `TestRatio` is the percentage of the materials should be examined as final examination. So, if you have not enough material for training, the student cannot be a success in the middle and final examination. Is it clear? A neural network works for such a simple student for learning/training. So, your network faces with over-fitting problems.

Comment: I also know this data division issue. Even if use 70% data for training it cannot provide me good output for very few new input data set.

To mention, i do not thing i have overfitting problems in my net, as i used some functions in matlab which helps to stop the network whenever any overfitting and underfitting happens.

Comment: Besides when my model is trained properly, i check with new input data (a huge amount of database), and works very well. But whenever i provide a few data points like less than 50, it shows abnormal output. This particular case is the problem i am facing with.

Comment: In NN, anything depends on training phase. Do you confident that support all the types of data in your dataset? I mean, If your test dataset consists of some untrained data in training phase, you cannot get good results. If so, you cannot apply NN and should focus on clustering modeling. Your test dataset should be near to training dataset structure, otherwise, NN is weak for this type of training.

Comment: Also, what is your division mode for training/validation/test sets? random? As you know, random division is the most appropriate division.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. In my case, data division method is random, and the network has few functions (in ANN toolbox in Matlab)which controls some features for example: to stop overfitting, undefitting, and early stopping. By using these, i got good output, even if 10% data is used for training.

Comment: @mmenvo, scientifically, 10% is not appropriate for training purposes. 10% is suitable for validation/testing portions.